# Not able to make service to service communication with SpringBoot and RestTemplate

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, resttemplate, hystrix

I have 2 SpringBoot application as restful service, when I am trying to established communication between those 2 service I am not able to fetch response from one service into other. My code is as follows.

Can anyone tell me what is wrong in my code due to which every time my code is going into fallback method.

1.EmployeeApplication

```
package io.employee.breaker;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;


@RestController
@SpringBootApplication
public class EmployeeApplication {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EmployeeApplication.class);
    @RequestMapping("/getEmployee")
    public Employee getEmployee() {
        log.info("Inside EmployeeApplication");
        Employee emp = new Employee(1,"Ankit");
        log.info("Return value");
        return emp;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EmployeeApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

2.ReadEmployeeApplication

```
 package io.employee.breaker;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.client.circuitbreaker.EnableCircuitBreaker;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@EnableCircuitBreaker
@RestController
@SpringBootApplication
@RequestMapping("/employee")
public class ReadEmployeeApplication {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ReadEmployeeApplication.class);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ReadEmployeeApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeService employeeService;

    @RequestMapping("/to-read")
    public Employee toRead() {
        log.info("Inside to read");
        return employeeService.readingList();
    }
}
```

Employee Service

```
package io.employee.breaker;

import java.net.URI;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import com.netflix.hystrix.contrib.javanica.annotation.HystrixCommand;

@ComponentScan(basePackages="io.employee.configuration")
@Service
public class EmployeeService {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EmployeeService.class);
    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @HystrixCommand(fallbackMethod="reliable")
    public Employee readingList() {
        log.info("Inside readingList");
        URI uri = URI.create("http://localhost:4040/getEmployee");
        log.info("restTemplate | "+restTemplate);
        ResponseEntity<Employee> e = restTemplate.getForEntity(uri, Employee.class);
        log.info("Employee | "+e.getBody().toString());
        return e.getBody();
    }

    public Employee reliable() {
        log.info("Inside reliable");
        return new Employee(2,"Jyoti");
    }
}
```

Configuration

```
package io.employee.configuration;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

@Component
public class Configuration {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Configuration.class);
    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        log.info("Creating Object of RestTemplate");
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        return restTemplate;
    }
}
```

logs

```
2018-05-14 16:00:41.507  INFO 4884 --- [nio-4041-exec-1] i.e.breaker.ReadEmployeeApplication      : Inside to read
2018-05-14 16:00:41.980  INFO 4884 --- [ployeeService-1] io.employee.breaker.EmployeeService      : Inside readingList
2018-05-14 16:00:41.980  INFO 4884 --- [ployeeService-1] io.employee.breaker.EmployeeService      : restTemplate | org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate@484300c9
2018-05-14 16:00:42.091  INFO 4884 --- [ployeeService-1] io.employee.breaker.EmployeeService      : Inside reliable
```

URI

```
http://localhost:4041/employee/to-read
http://localhost:4040/getEmployee
```

pom.xml

read-employee/pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.ankit</groupId>
    <artifactId>read-employee</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>read-employee</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Finchley.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
     </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>


</project>
```

employee/pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.ankit</groupId>
    <artifactId>employee</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>employee</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
       <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
       </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>


</project>
```

Comment: Hi, you could add to you application.properties : 
"logging.level.com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand=DEBUG"

Doing so, you'll be able to see the reason of HystrixCommand going to fallback

Comment: Hi, I added the mentioned entry in application.properties but it is not working for me.

    "server.port=4041
    logging.level.com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand=DEBUG"

Comment: Strange you should see some logging info with the exception causing HystrixCommand falling back.
Would you share you pom.xml ?

Comment: When working with microservices of Spring Boot Applications, it is highly recommended to look into Eureka:   https://spring.io/blog/2015/01/20/microservice-registration-and-discovery-with-spring-cloud-and-netflix-s-eureka

Comment: I have updated the pom.xml in question. Please verify and and let me know my mistakes.

Comment: Can you access http://localhost:4040/getEmployee from browser? and where have you mentioned the ports 4040 and 4041?

Comment: Yes I am able to access localhost:4040/getEmployee  from browser. I mentioned the ports in "application.properties" of both the application. My "employee" application is running on 4040 port and "read-employee" is running on 4041 port